# High response times Parse Server

Tags: parse-server

I just set up a Heroku Standard Dyno connected to Mlab M1 dedicated cluster and am seeing high response times in New Relic for some calls.

Digging a bit into New Relic's transaction trace I notice a component called Middleware: anonymous thats taking up 82% of the request.

[image: Transaction Trace]

Anyone have any ideas what that could be or a way to maybe try to debug this.. the connections between the dyno and mlab is quite fast.

Thoughts?

Comment: Even I am getting the same error.